# Fetching List of Documents from Firestore in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of document IDs and I would like to pull these documents in my swift project. For some reason, nothing is being returned.

example document:

[image]

example model:

```
struct MyModel: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {

@DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
var title: String
var content: String}
```

example Code:

```
self.db
    .collection("examplePath")
    .whereField("id", in: ["1D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8", "8D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8"])
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("no documents \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        print(documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> MyModel? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyModel.self))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `in` operator with document IDs, you can use [`FieldPath.documentID()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldPath#/c:objc(cs)FIRFieldPath(cm)documentID):

```
self.db
    .collection("examplePath")
    .whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), in: ["1D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8", "8D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8"])
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try this, Xcode tells me that: 'Type 'Firestore' has no member 'FieldPath''

Comment: @neo can you try just `FieldPath.documentID()` ?

Comment: Xcode accepts this but I'm still not getting anything. I even tried: .whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), isEqualTo: "1D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8") - but I get nothing in return. When I remove the whereField, all items returns correctly. I've copy&pasted the ID as it shown in Firestore but nothing helps

Comment: Another thing that might help: When I output the results that I get without the whereField I get this as a referral to the docID: [MyApp.MyModel(_id: FirebaseFirestoreSwift.DocumentID<Swift.String>(value: Optional("1D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8")

Comment: OK, I got it. I've used this query and it worked: .whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), in: [Optional("1D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8"), Optional("8D9815E9-54D4-468E-BH23-791D2AE82DA8")])